# How do I get JDK-8.0 to recognize the -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore parameter?

Tags: java, ssl, fiddler

I am trying to add a certificate to a jar file command line app so I can use Fiddler to inspect the HTTPS requests it generates.

My JDK is `AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot` on Windows 10 x64.

The cert was exported from Fiddler and the keystore was generated without any issues, using [this article](https://coderwall.com/p/3g7-ma/capture-https-traffic-from-java-applications-with-fiddler).

However, I get this error message when I run the program:

> Error: Unrecognized option:
> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/code/cert/FiddlerKeystore

This is the command line I'm executing, it works perfectly without the trustStore/proxy args:

```
java -jar etl.jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:/code/cert/FiddlerKeystore" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=fiddler -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DproxyPort=8888 (plus app-specific settings)
```

What could be causing this?  I'm assuming that a JDK would include javax.net.ssl libraries by default.

Comment: Put JVM options, including sysprop settings using `-D`, **BEFORE THE JARNAME** with `-jar`, or the mainclass name otherwise; see e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html (also for j9+ before modulename with `-m/--module` and for j11+ before sourcename)

Comment: PS: you could also see the data sent and received, without Fiddler, by setting sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl,plaintext`

Comment: Thanks, perhaps you should add that as an answer instead of a comment?